# How to find the 32 bit version of zlib with CMake

Tags: cmake, 32bit-64bit, zlib

I want to offer my users the option to choose between a 32 bit and a 64 bit build and switch between them using an option. If the option is set, I add `-m32` to `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`, `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, and `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`. I also call `set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY FIND_LIBRARY_USE_LIB64_PATHS OFF)`. This worked fine so far, but now I tried to find the library zlib and consistently get the 64 bit version causing the linker to fail.

I found [this old thread](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2014-June/057943.html), which has the same issue but no solution that works for me. Like Glenn Coombs, I don't want to ask my users to understand how they have to call cmake to get a 32 bit build, so `CC="gcc -m32" cmake` does not work for me.

**Edit:**
Turns out this doesn't even work with the solution proposed in the email thread. Here is a small example:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "zlib.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << ZLIB_VERSION << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pointer size: " << sizeof(void*) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(usezlib32)
add_executable(usezlib32 main.cpp)

find_package(ZLIB)
if (ZLIB_FOUND)
    include_directories(${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(usezlib32 ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

Calling `g++ -m32 main.cpp -lz` produces a working binary, but calling `CC="gcc -m32" CXX="g++ -m32" cmake && make` crashes with the following error:

```
/opt/anaconda/lib/libz.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
```

I guess the question is why CMake looks in a different path than g++.

Comment: As far as I know, `find_library` searches only according to the filename, it doesn't perform additional checks on files it finds. What paths to your 32-bit and 64-bit zlib libraries?

Comment: Yes, it seems like CMake just uses the first `libz.so` it finds. g++ seems to be smarter about it. The question is how to make CMake that smart.

Comment: To answer your question, g++ finds the correct version in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libz.so`. Resolving relative paths that is `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so`. CMake looks in `/opt/anaconda/lib/libz.so`.

Comment: Do you pass some weird path to /opt? Otherwise CMake would no search in /opt.

Comment: I installed anaconda which adds itself to the path. g++ seems not to be affected by this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMake command [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html) performes searching taking into account **filename only**, it doesn't perform additional checks on files it finds.

So, the only way to find 32-bit library instead of 64-bit one is making directory with 32-bit library to be **searched before** one for 64-bit:

- Setting property [FIND_LIBRARY_USE_LIB64_PATHS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_gbl/FIND_LIBRARY_USE_LIB64_PATHS.html) may *disable* search for some paths with 64-bit libraries. It works only for paths contained '64' or 'lib64' (see algorithm of `find_library` for more details).

As your path `/opt/anaconda/lib/libz.so` doesn't fit to this rule, this property doesn't help you.

- Setting `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH` *CMake cache variable* to list of directories, contained 32-bit libraries. So these directories will be searched before others.

In you case you may do follows:

```
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu" CACHE PATH "<desc>")
```

Alternatively, this variable may be passed to `cmake` with `-D` option.

- Setting `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH` *environment variable* to list of directories, contained 32-bit libraries. So these directories will be searched before others.

In you case you may do follows:

```
set(ENV{CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu")
```

It could be that paths to other non-system libraries are stored in this variable too. So be careful when change it: you may break searching of other libraries needed for your project.

- Setting CMake or environment variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, or other variables which affects on `find_package(XXX)` for specific package. E.g., for zlib one can set `ZLIB_ROOT` variable pointed to zlib installation directory.

While this way definitely helps to find needed version of library, it is more target-specific then other approaches.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. This will help get it working on my system, but feels like hard-coding something into the CMake file that could be different from system to system. So whether this will work on another machine depends on the specific setup of that machine. `g++ -lz` will locate the right version independent of the setup. I hoped that CMake would abstract from that and that FindZLIB would handle exactly this kind of machine-dependence instead of introducing it. If there is no way to do this in CMake, I'll accept your answer, but I'll wait for a bit, in case someone has an idea.

Comment: To be clear, my goal here is not to create a build system that works for me. I want something that I can give to someone else with a minimal amount of documentation. I would like to avoid documentation like "if you happen to have a 64 library of zlib installed (for example by installing anaconda) and that library comes before the 32bit version on the PATH, then you need to locate your 32 bit library and set the environment variable ...".

Comment: Yes, I perfectly understand that my answer is not what you eventually want. It just describes **why it behave so** (that is, why your attempts are failed). The answer may helps others to configure 32-bit project on **particular machine**. It could be that my question hints someone to find proper decision for your problem. Just a guess: Can `anaconda` be configured to install 64-bit libraries under `lib64/` subdirectory? In that case `FIND_LIBRARY_USE_LIB64_PATHS` would work.

Comment: Maybe anaconda could be installed differently, but that would also only solve the issue on my machine. Looks like there is no way to make it work in general, though, so I accepted your answer. Thanks.